# Export an element/tag to PNG in Electron

Tags: electron

Is it possible to export a tag/element in Electron to a PNG file? how?

In my particular case, I'm trying to webview, so, it's not a simple case, as it might have anything in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can screenshot a portion of a `webContents` with the [`capturePage` API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentscapturepagerect-callback). So to capture just an isolated DOM element, you'd have to get the dimensions of it and then pass that to `capturePage` and then save it as a PNG using the [NativeImage API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/native-image.md)

```
const { x: left, y: top, width, height } = document.querySelector('my-element').getBoundingClientRect();

webContents.capturePage({x, y, width, height}, (image) => {
  //image is a NativeImage instance.  
  const buff = image.toPNG();
  //now you can save it to disk or do whatever
})
```

You can do this is in a webview as well. Just run in it in preload script and use IPC to communicate with the outer parent renderer process.

Comment: Just want to add that all values must be rounded to the nearest whole number to work.